# Repeat same Data for Calendar Date in SparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a calendar table

| c_date |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-01-02 |
| 2020-01-03 |
| 2020-01-04 |
| ..... |
| 2020-12-31 |

I have the main table

| ID | col_A | col_B | col_C | col_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | 2020-05-05 |
| 2 | A | B | C | 2020-04-05 |
| 3 | X | Y | Z | 2020-02-02 |

I want the output as date to get repeat for Calendar days starting from col_Date in second table.

Output should be:

| col_A | col_B | col_C | c_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | 2020-05-05 |
| A | B | C | 2020-05-06 |
| A | B | C | 2020-05-07 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| A | B | C | 2020-12-31 |
| X | Y | Z | 2020-02-02 |
| X | Y | Z | 2020-02-03 |
| X | Y | Z | 2020-02-04 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| X | Y | Z | 2020-12-31 |

What I tried: Correlated query, which works in SQL Server but not in SparkSQL (Databricks)

```
select A, B, C, c_date FROM calendar_table x
inner join main_table m on x.col_date = (select max(c_date) from main_table h
  where h.A = m.A and h.B = m.b and h.C = m.C and h.c_date <= x.col_date )
where 1=1
```

NOT Working in SparkSQL
NOTE :  It should start only from the MAX of that Month. Please help rewrite the query.

Comment: the statement `select col_A, col_B, col_C, c_Date from calendar_table c join main_table m on m.col_Date <= c.c_Date` returns the expected result. But looking at your query, there are probably some details about the main table missing in the question?

Comment: The repetition of data should start from the MAX of the col_date. To accomodate that, I have used the subquery. But somehow, for 1 data its fine, for multiple data, duplicates are coming.

Comment: I have edited 1 more row. It clarifies the output.

Comment: also for the updated main table, the statement in my first comment returns the expected result in my test. Which result do you get?

Comment: Yes, this query will work, only if 1 record present for that Month. If 2 records present, I need to take the MAX date , for that month and repeat.  Here comes the problem of correlation.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the maximum date per combination of `col_A`, `col_B` and `col_C` from the main table using a [with statement](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-cte.html) and then join all dates from the calendar table that are later or equal to this maximum date.

```sql
with max_date (date, col_A, col_B, col_C) as 
  (select max(col_Date) as date, col_A, col_B, col_C from main_table 
    group by col_A, col_B, col_C)
select c_date, col_A, col_B, col_C from max_date h 
join calendar_table c on c.c_date >= h.date
```